# How to set alarm/alert if my system cpu usage reaches a particular threshold?

Tags: linux, bash, email, cpu-usage

I have written a shell scripting for monitoring the system CPU usage and memory usage. I need to know how to send notification to mail that my system reached particular threshold (example:- 90%).

My code:

```
#! /bin/bash
printf "Date\t\t\tMemory\t\tDisk\t\tCPU\n"
end=$((SECONDS+30))
while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do
CURRENTDATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"`
MEMORY=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf " \t%.2f%%\t\t", $3*100/$2 }')
DISK=$(df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "%s\t\t", $5}')
CPU=$(top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "%.2f%%\t\t\n", $(NF-2)}')
echo  ${CURRENTDATE} "$MEMORY$DISK$CPU"

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should use some monitoring solution (Nagios, Zabbix FTW!). But if you really want to use your custom script you can just use `mail` program.

```
echo "Current CPU USAGE $CPU" | mail -s "This is subject like: CPU WARNING" my.email@example.com
```

You can also use `ssmpt`. I didn't tested it but there is simple article about it https://www.howtogeek.com/51819/how-to-setup-email-alerts-on-linux-using-gmail/.

Comment: Tried with the command, it's not working.But the link you gave for ssmpt  works for me.Thanks!